# MAMP strange behaviour : php read external file from an http:// is very slow, but from https:// is quick

Tags: php, mamp

I have a simple PHP script to read a remote file line-by-line, and then JSON decode it. On the production server all works ok, but on my local machine (MAMP stack, OSX) the PHP hangs. It is very slow, and takes more than 2 minutes to produce the JSON file. I think it's the `json_decode()` that is freezing. Why only on MAMP?

I think it's stuck in `while` loop, because I can't show the final `$str` variable that is the result of all the lines.

In case you are wondering why I need to read the file line-by-line, it's because in the real scenario, the remote JSON file is a 40MB text file. My only good performance result is like this, but any good suggestion?

Is there a configuration in `php.ini` to help solve this?

```
// The path to the JSON File
$fileName = 'http://www.xxxx.xxx/response-single.json';
    
//Open the file in "reading only" mode.
$fileHandle = fopen($fileName, "r");
    
//If we failed to get a file handle, throw an Exception.
if($fileHandle === false){
    error_log("erro handle");
    throw new Exception('Could not get file handle for: ' . $fileName);
}
   
//While we haven't reach the end of the file.
$str = "";
while(!feof($fileHandle)) {
       
    //Read the current line in.
    $line = fgets($fileHandle);
    $str .= $line;
}
    
//Finally, close the file handle.
fclose($fileHandle);
   
$json = json_decode($str, true); // decode the JSON into an associative array
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Put some `echo` statements in your code to display the timestamp at each step to determine where the delay really is. It might be that your connection to the destination URL is being throttled.

Comment: Yes...i put an echo inside the while.... to show the $line and it shows that the lines all are processed. 
I also put an echo after the fclose($fileHandle); to show the $str variable... and php is stuck... even in debug.log it take forever to show... 2 minutes for test file json of some kb, 500 lines only. 

Maybe some MAMP configuration ? or resource limit ? i never saw php acting like this.

Comment: I put also an echo before $fclose($fileHandle) and with the same result. I think the While loop is having a strange behaviour to EOF, it quicky reads all the lines...but i take forever to get out of the while loop.

Comment: *why i need to read the file line by line, its because in real scenario, the remote json file is a 40MB text file* but your still just building a string, you might as well do `$json = json_decode(file_get_contents(...))` for better performance and way less code

Comment: Yes, but I test the both ways... and line by line is quicker. But your point don't resolve my main issue.

Comment: So the delay is after the `while` loop but before the call to `fclose()`?

Comment: The main problem is json_decode the file, i need a associative array.
I also change the code for file_get_contents()

        error_log("Get and Json File");
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName),true);
        error_log("Get and Json File - Complete");

And it take 1,5 minute to see the last error_log, i dont get it... it's a small json file, only 500 lines. 
I am using php 7.3

Comment: @kmoser, yes... using while loop yes... but just for troubleshotting, i tried the the file_get_contents() function and the delay is the same.

Comment: I must also tell, that this script is run by an ajax call, xhr request. I dont think it matters the origin call, but its more info about this issue.

Comment: Rather than checking `while(!feof($fileHandle))`, try `while(($line=fgets($fileHandle)) !== NULL)`.

Comment: @kmoser, same result :(

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23117415/378779

Comment: More updated info... i copy the json file to local server...and work flawless. So the problem is the file  on external site `http://xxxxxxxx.yyy/file.json` because the code works well on local json file. 
Something in MAMP is slowing down the external request to file.

Comment: I found the cause !!! its path protocol. With `$filename = 'http://www.yyy/response.json';` , it freezes the server for 1 a 2 minutes, i changed the file to other server with https protocol, and change `$filename = 'https://www.yyy/response.json';` and it work !!!! Why this behaviour in MAMP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. It is path protocol.

With

```php
$filename = 'http://www.yyy/response.json';
```

It freezes the server for 1 to 2 minutes.
I changed the file to another server with https protocol, and used

```php
$filename = 'https://www.yyy/response.json';
```

and it works.